# How I can get last row of each day from big mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I have table more than 10 millions of rows.
I can get first row of each day by query

```
select *
from history_average_crypto_stats
where `asset_id` = 1 
  and `created_at` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
group by date(`created_at`) 
order by `created_at` asc
```

But I need last and tried this query

```
select history_average_crypto_stats.*
from history_average_crypto_stats
join (
  select MAX(`id`) id
  from history_average_crypto_stats
  where `asset_id` = 1 
    and `created_at` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
  group by date(`created_at`)
) last ON history_average_crypto_stats.`id` = last.`id`
```

But it takes more than 24 seconds...

I need less than 1 sec.
Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `history_average_crypto_stats` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `asset_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `price` double(20,6) NOT NULL,
  `volume` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `circulating_supply` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_supply` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `history_average_crypto_stats`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `history_average_pairs_currency_id_asset_id_foreign` (`created_at`,`asset_id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `asset_id` (`asset_id`);

ALTER TABLE `history_average_crypto_stats`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select h.*
from history_average_crypto_stats h
where h.created_at = (
    select max(h1.created_at)
    from history_average_crypto_stats h1
    where h1.created_at >= date(h.created_at) and h1.created_at < date(h.created_at) + interval 1 day
)
```

This uses column `created_at` to identify the last record per day. It is unclear why you use `id` instead (unless there are duplicate `created_at`).

For performance, consider an index on `(created_at)`.

If you want to filer on `asset_id` too, as in your original code, then:

```
select h.*
from history_average_crypto_stats h
where h.asset_id = 1 and h.created_at = (
    select max(h1.created_at)
    from history_average_crypto_stats h1
    where h1.asset_id = h.asset_id
      and h1.created_at >= date(h.created_at) 
      and h1.created_at < date(h.created_at) + interval 1 day
)
```

And then have an index on `(asset_id, created_at)` - I suspect that is is a better fit for your query than your original index on `(created_at, asset_id)`, because of the range condition on `created_at`.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can also try window functions, and see if performance is better:

```
select *
from (
    select h.*, row_number() over(partition by date(created_at) order by created_at desc) rn
    from history_average_crypto_stats 
    where asset_id = 1
) h
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I was waiting more than minute, but query was not executed

Comment: @FunnyCOFE: Do you have the recommended index in place? Also, you might want to wait more than 1 minute, so we can get to know the actual execution time. I also edited my answer with more suggestions.

Comment: Yes, I have. I'll leave it until morning. I'll see the execution time in the morning